# preg_match expression help

Tags: php, preg-match, preg-match-all

Can't seem to figure this one out.  Just trying to preg match for a specific variable name in a link URL:

```
<a href="http://something.com?variable=name">GenericLink</a>
```

How do I get the variable=name out of this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extract the whole url and then use parse_url();

```
$str = '<a href="http://something.com?variable=name">GenericLink</a>';

preg_match('/href="([^"]*)/i',$str,$matches);
var_dump(parse_url($matches[1]));
```

Comment: One more step: `$url = parse_url($matches[1]); parse_str($url['query'], $vars); var_dump($vars['variable']);`

Comment: $url = parse_url($matches[1], PHP_URL_QUERY); parse_str($url, $vars);